# path with a dot in web.config <location>

Tags: iis, web-config, basic-authentication

I need to add a location element in my web.config file, but the path starts with a dot (and I don't think I can change that path, it's for [letsencrypt](http://letsencrypt.org) automation).

If I let the dot, like in `<location path=".well-known/acme-challenge"></location>`, the site doesn't start at all (I think the web.config file is not parsed at all because I get the page asking me to configure customErrors, but it is already configured and usually works fine)

If I remove the dot, like in `<location path="well-known/acme-challenge"></location>` the web.config file is correctly loaded, but of course that doesn't help me to configure anything at the location I wish.

The final goal is to disable basic authentication (which I need for the rest of the site) on this path only ; I don't even know if I'll be able to set this up in a `<location>` element.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've "solved" my problem by removing basic authentication on the whole site (it was temporary anyway, until the final authentication system was implemented). Still interested to know if there is another solution though.

Comment: There always is a possibility of creating separate web.config inside the dot folder (.well-known) folder.

Comment: I'd second Ondrej's suggestion.  The dot is a forbidden starting character for locations, but you can drop a config file into the folder as an effective workaround.

Comment: Even better then create a second web-config inside .well-known folder is changing the web-config inside acme-challenge to allow all users to current path! I dont even know why this isnt there by default if its required... Edit: Seems new versions already add the security section but only on creation, it doesnt update old web.configs....

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had a similar problem where I had a ASP.NET Forms site that was forcing authentication on all pages.

To expand on the accepted answer, here is the exact web.config I put in the `/.well-known` folder (NOT the `/.well-known/acme-challenge` folder):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- This will stop any redirects you have at the higher level -->
    <httpRedirect enabled="false" />

    <!-- This will stop any integrated mode settings you have at the higher level -->
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <!-- This will allow unauthenticated users to acme-challenge subfolder -->
  <location path="acme-challenge">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

After adding this file, I was able to use [EcdsaAcmeNet](https://github.com/vrbyjimmy/EcdsaAcmeNet) to use Lets Encrypt with the site in IIS.

Comment: Thanks for posting a full example!

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by Ondrej Svedjdar in comments, the solution is so simple I didn't think about it.

Just add another web.config file in the folder where you need it.